# vfork() failed with error no 513

Tags: linux, posix, vfork

In RHEL 6.6 based environment, we are doing IO from a thread which is created by XML rpc server. The thread executes the external command which does vfork().
The vfork() system call fails with errorno 513.

What may be the possible reasons for it?

Answer (score 0):

From description into kernel sources error 513 occurs if parent thread have pending signals (SIGTERM, SIGUSR1, SIGSEGV and others).

Comment: @AHTOH- Thanks for replying...What will cause signals to be pending in parent thread?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know :)

Comment: Can you provide sources with calling vfork? Maybe vfork calling into signal handler context or with another strange conditions?